# What is the meaning of assigning to an empty matrix in Scilab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, scilab, is-empty, rowdeleting

In one of my programs, I wanted to delete a row of a matrix. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iBfpcVLnuc) video tutorial online. It says that to delete, for example, the first row, write

```
A(1,:)=[]
```

However I don't understand what this exactly means. The LHS is simply the first row of the matrix. We are assigning that to an empty matrix and that somehow deletes the 1st row. Can you shed more light on what exactly is the function of an empty matrix and what is going on in the background?

Comment: I am not sure there is anything to explain. If you make a row equal to empty (i.e. nothing), then the row is nothing, and if something existed before, and now is equal to nothing, then it has been deleted, by per the definition of "delete". I assume that internally, in the very low level case, then MATLAB makes a copy of the 2nd to last row and overwrites the memory to return a new variable, but all this is opaque and not too important, unless you are very very worried about memory.

Comment: Oh I get it now. But one more doubt. Shouldn't there be a dimension error as LHS is a 1-by-n matrix and RHS is a 0-by-0 matrix.

Comment: You are right, but the language is designed to detect this.

Comment: Oh great. Now I get this completely. Thanks